# .htaccess prevent default folder 301 redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a very small site with my .htaccess set up to allow urls like:

```
mysite.com/brand/login
mysite.com/brand/dashboard
mysite.com/controller
```

These all redirect to:

```
mysite.com/driver.php?___=brand/login
mysite.com/driver.php?___=brand/dashboard
mysite.com/driver.php?___=controller
```

I'm simply using one rewrite rule for this:

```
RewriteRule ^(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+/?)*)$ index.php?___=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But anyway, it works great, until I have a page with the same name as a folder in my site.

```
// I navigate to:
mysite.com/javascript

// The site automatically provides a 301 redirect to
mysite.com/javascript/? ___=javascript
```

And now that ugly URL is showing up in my users' browsers. Is there any way to tell the site that I want to take care of all redirects myself?

**EDIT:** I determined this using fiddler. Another example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welp found the answer right after posting this. This line in .htaccess fixed the problem.

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

I then, of course, had to clear my browser cache to make it forget about the 301.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

> The DirectorySlash directive determines whether mod_dir should fixup
>   URLs pointing to a directory or not.
>
> Typically if a user requests a resource without a trailing slash,
>   which points to a directory, mod_dir redirects him to the same
>   resource, but with trailing slash

And a security warning:

> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information
>   disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active
>   (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid resource (say,
>   index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL.
>   In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html
>   file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory
>   contents.**